# How to embed text from wikipedia?

Tags: embed, wikipedia

I have pages on my site of some famous personalities, I want to embed short description of them from wikipedia (similar to what google shows on the side when you search for subject that exists on wikipedia), and have the possibility to style the text too, is there a ways to do that dynamically?

[image: google example]

Comment: [Google helps](https://www.google.com/search?q=wikipedia+api): https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page, http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-phpwikipedia/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use the [Freebase API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/getting-started) (in particular, the [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview)) to do something like this. Basically, you want to fetch the `/common/topic/description` attribute, like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/02mjmr?filter=/common/topic/description

(You can also use Freebase to get most of the other attributes that display in the [Knowledge Graph](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/search/knowledge.html)).